# Count RTP Sequence number from multicast stream

Tags: c, sockets, multicast, rtp

I trying count RTP Sequence number from multicast stream and a determine lost packages.

Please see the following C code:

```
int sock, bytesRead;
char buffer[MAXBUFSIZE];
uint16_t seq = 0;
uint16_t eseq = 0;
struct sockaddr_in saddr;
socklen_t socklen;

    for(;;) {
        bytesRead = recvfrom(sock, buffer, MAXBUFSIZE, 0,
                             (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, &socklen);
        if (bytesRead) {
            seq = (buffer[2] << 8)+buffer[3];
            eseq++;
            if (seq != eseq) {
                std::cerr << " SEQ = " << seq << " ESEC = " << eseq << "\n";
                eseq = seq;
            }
        }
    }
```

And I received the following results:

```
12:47:44 SEQ = 58112 ESEC = 57856
12:47:45 SEQ = 57984 ESEC = 58240
12:47:45 SEQ = 58368 ESEC = 58112
12:47:45 SEQ = 58240 ESEC = 58496
12:47:45 SEQ = 58624 ESEC = 58368
12:47:46 SEQ = 58496 ESEC = 58752
12:47:46 SEQ = 58880 ESEC = 58624
12:47:46 SEQ = 58752 ESEC = 59008
12:47:46 SEQ = 59136 ESEC = 58880
12:47:47 SEQ = 59008 ESEC = 59264
12:47:47 SEQ = 59392 ESEC = 59136
12:47:47 SEQ = 59264 ESEC = 59520
```

Error raised with each `128` RTP package and as you can see `|ESEC - SEQ| = 256`, I also removed RTP headers and write data in a file.mpg and video playing fine without errors and artefacts.

**Please explain how can I properly count RTP Sequence number from multicast stream**

Comment: It isn't [tag:c] code.

Comment: This `(buffer[2] << 8)` overflows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an overflow in your conversion(left-shift) due to buffer that is a `signed char` array. It is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

You could test/solve it using this code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint16_t seq1;
    uint16_t seq2;
    uint16_t seq3;

             char buffer1[] = {0, 0, 0xE8, 0x80};
    unsigned char buffer2[] = {0, 0, 0xE8, 0x80};

    seq1 = (buffer1[2] << 8)+buffer1[3];
    printf("seq1: %d\n", seq1);

    seq2 = (buffer2[2] << 8)+buffer2[3];
    printf("seq2: %d\n", seq2);

    seq3 = buffer1[2];
    seq3 = (seq3 << 8)+buffer2[3];
    printf("seq3: %d\n", seq3);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
seq1: 59264
seq2: 59520
seq3: 59520
```

As you can see using a `signed char` (`seq1`) buffer the conversion is wrong. 
The exaple shows what happened with last line of result you posted.